# WP Programmatically move the ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone

I have a `ScrollViewer` and I'm filling it with controls for about 2 screen heights. At the bottom I have a button which clears the `ScrollViewer` and refills it with different controls. The problem is when I refill it, the scroll distance remains where my button was. I need the `ScrollViewer` to scroll up to the top. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to use the [ScrollToVerticalOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method of the `ScrollViewer`.

```
myScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0);
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't get search to give me this.